# How to call SemaphoreSlim.Release() without risking app failure?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, try-catch, semaphore, rategate

I'm trying to use the new `SemaphoreSlim` class in .NET 4.0 to rate-limit a fast-paced loop that can run indefinitely. In unit testing this, I've found that if the loop is tight enough and the degree of parallelism is high enough, the `SemaphoreSlim` can throw an uncatchable exception when you call `Release()`, **even if** you check the `.Count` property first and lock around the semaphore instance itself during the entire check-count/release sequence.

This exception takes down the app, period. There is no catching it as far as I can tell.

Digging deeper, I discovered that the `SemaphoreSlim` is trying to access it's own `.AvailableWaitHandle` property internally during the `Release()` call, it throws the exception there, not from me accessing the `SemaphoreSlim` instance itself. (I had to debug with Debug->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions->Thrown all checked in Visual Studio to discover this; you can't catch it at runtime. See [The Uncatchable Exception](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2006/10/uncatchable-exception) for more details.)

My question is, does anyone know of a bullet-proof way to use this class without risking immediate app termination in such a case?

Note: The semaphore instance is wrapped in a RateGate instance, the code for which can be found in this article: [Better Rate Limiting in .NET](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/10/better-rate-limiting-with-dot-net/).

**UPDATE**: 
I'm adding complete console app code to reproduce. Both answers contributed to the solution; see below for explanation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using PennedObjects.RateLimiting;

namespace RateGateForceTerminateDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static int _secondsToRun = 10;
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            OptimizeMaxThreads();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception, terminating={0}:{1}", e.IsTerminating, e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate app.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static void OptimizeMaxThreads() {
            int processors = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int processorsSq = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(processors,2));
            int threads = 1;
            double result;
            Tuple<int, double> maxResult = new Tuple<int, double>(threads, 0);
            while (threads <= processorsSq) {
                Console.WriteLine("Running for {0}s with upper limit of {1} threads... ", _secondsToRun, threads);
                result = TestThrottling(10000000, threads, _secondsToRun);
                Console.WriteLine("Ok. Result is {0:N0} ops/s", result);
                Console.WriteLine();
                if(result > maxResult.Item2)
                    maxResult = new Tuple<int, double>(threads, result);
                threads *= 2;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} threads achieved max throughput of {1:N0}", maxResult.Item1, maxResult.Item2);
        }
        static double TestThrottling(int limitPerSecond, int maxThreads, int maxRunTimeSeconds) {
            int completed = 0;
            RateGate gate = new RateGate(limitPerSecond, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            ParallelLoopResult res = new ParallelLoopResult();
            ParallelOptions parallelOpts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads };
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try {
                res = Parallel.For<int>(0, 1000000000, parallelOpts, () => 0, (num, state, subtotal) =>
                {
                    bool succeeded = gate.WaitToProceed(10000);
                    if (succeeded) {
                        subtotal++;
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Gate timed out for thread {0}; {1:N0} iterations, elapsed {2}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, subtotal, sw.Elapsed);
                        // return subtotal;
                    }
                    if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > maxRunTimeSeconds) {
                        Console.WriteLine("MaxRunTime expired for thread {0}, last succeeded={1}, iterations={2:N0}, elapsed={3}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, succeeded, subtotal, sw.Elapsed);
                        state.Break();
                    }
                    return subtotal;
                }, (subtotal) => Interlocked.Add(ref completed, subtotal));
            }
            catch (AggregateException aggEx) {
                Console.WriteLine(aggEx.Flatten().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            double throughput = completed / Math.Max(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Done at {0}, finished {1:N0} iterations, IsCompleted={2}, LowestBreakIteration={3:N0}, ",
                sw.Elapsed,
                completed,
                res.IsCompleted,
                (res.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue ? res.LowestBreakIteration.Value : double.NaN));
            Console.WriteLine();
            //// Uncomment the following 3 lines to stop prevent the ObjectDisposedException:
            //Console.WriteLine("We should not hit the dispose statement below without a console pause.");
            //Console.Write("Hit any key to continue... ");
            //Console.ReadKey(false);
            gate.Dispose();
            return throughput;
        }
    }
}
```

So using @dtb's solution it was still possible for a thread "a" get past the `_isDisposed` check, and yet have thread "b" dispose the semaphore before thread "a" hit `Release()`. I found that adding a lock around the _semaphore instance in both the ExitTimerCallback and Dispose methods. @Peter Ritchie's suggestion led me to additionally cancel and dispose the timer, *before* disposing the semaphore. These two things combination let the program complete and dispose of the RateGate properly with no exceptions.

Since I wouldn't have gotten this without that input I don't want to answer myself. But since StackOverflow is more useful when complete answers are available, I'll accept whichever person first posts a patch or pseudo-patch that successfully survives the console app above.

Comment: Can you add code for a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Looking with ILspy at the code of the Release method, there doesn't seem to be an access to the AvailableWaitHandle property, just the m_waitHandle field. Where exactly does the exception originate?

Comment: I will try to cobble together a complete runnable demo tomorrow, but the short description would be to grab the RateGate class from here, http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/10/better-rate-limiting-with-dot-net/, instantiate it in a using block with a limit of, say, 5 million per second, then use Parallel.For to call WaitToProceed() as fast as you in a loop can with as many threads as you can.

Comment: Is it an ObjectDisposedException? I get one pretty fast. BTW, there are some questionable things in that RateGate class, like the use of Environment.TickCount. I also note that the RateGate class seems geared towards slow rates, not millions of actions per second.

Comment: BTW an ObjectDisposedException is not uncatchable; it's just thrown without a suitable exception handler and therefore bubbles up to the thread. You can catch it by attaching an event handler to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event.

Comment: Thanks, @dtb. It was indeed an ObjectDisposedException (though a handler in the timer callback wouldn't catch it when I tried). I'm sure that class could be improved for higher resolution situations; my tests with it were fine up to about 2.5 million ops/sec if my thread count was in the single-digits, but the Parallel.For using it would only give me ~5k ops/sec if I let it spawn 30+ threads. Ideally I'd like to know the per-thread overhead of the throttle itself, but that's another question.

Comment: Interestingly, I was still able to make the app force terminate after trying both of the answers so far below. I will add source to the original question.

Comment: I will add this detail to the question later as well, but incidentally I did add an handler to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. However, since IsTerminating was true on the UnhandledExceptionEventArgs, the app still shuts down as soon as the handler returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're spawned a bunch of threads to work with a RateGate object that gets disposed before those threads are done using it.  i.e. the threads are still running after your code exits from the using block.
UPDATE: if you do what you described in your comment; but don't use a using block you don't get the problem.  the exception I witnessed was actually an ObjectDisposedException; which would make sense if the RateGate was disposed before code was done using it...

Comment: Skipping semaphore disposal completely did circumvent the problem. To make the rate limiter a bit more thread-safe (and facilitate safe disposal), I added extra checks & a lock around the semaphore instance during the timer callback (see addendum to question). The timer callback should be very infrequent relative to `.WaitToProceed()` calls on the limiter (which calls `.Wait(int)` on the semaphore instance), so the performance penalty isn't measurable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the RateGate class you're using. It has an internal Timer that runs its code even after the RateGate instance is disposed. This code includes a call to Release on a disposed SemaphoreSlim.

*Fix:*

```
@@ -88,7 +88,8 @@
    int exitTime;
    while (_exitTimes.TryPeek(out exitTime)
            && unchecked(exitTime - Environment.TickCount) <= 0)
    {
+       if (_isDisposed) return;
        _semaphore.Release();
        _exitTimes.TryDequeue(out exitTime);
    }
```

Comment: This contributed to the answer, but I was still able to reproduce the exception after this change. With enough threads are running in a tight enough loop, `_isDisposed` was `false` when evaluated, but amazingly, the semaphore was disposed by the time `_semaphore.Release()` was called on very next line.